# Dropdown list in Table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, drop-down-menu, xcode4.2

i want to add a drop down list For e.g:
I need two menus like chats and soups.

In chat i have to display some chat items
 similarly in soup items i need to display some soup items.

While selecting the chat menu, the soup menu items should hidden and soup menu bar to be pushed down displayed with an right arrow similarly when i select soup menu chat menu items should hidden and chat menu bar to be pushed up with a right arrow. How can i add this in using  `UITableView`  ..

Comment: I used this : [AccordionView for iOS](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/accordionview), Ask if you have any problem implementing it.

Comment: hi i used that  project u mentioned. I downloaded and i built it gets crashed and shows [ViewController expandButtonTapped:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a13cb0
while i click expand it displays above. I checked the code but still i got this error !!!!

Comment: i am using xcode 4.2 is this the issue of framework!?

Comment: It worked perfectly for me. It can be a issue. Ask the Developer about this in comment section. If you are using 4.2 for learning purpose it is okay, but to make live app you should upgrade your Xcode.

Comment: Try this on your side : [Expandable List](http://www.filedropper.com/expandablelist), works on mine.

Comment: i tried the above but it shows error "synthesis-of-weak-property-only-allowed-in-arc-or-gc-mode "whether i have to disable arc mode bcoz after disabling i got   the current deployment target doesnot supports automated weak reference what to do!! i searched a lot !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the subtable master which acts as drop down in table view itself.attached link below

**https://github.com/ajkoshy7/SubTable**

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `UISegmentedControl`. The user can switch between different tableViews, depending on which segment is selected.  The selected tableViewController is displayed inside a containerView.

This is what I've been doing in a [Composite Gospel app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/composite-gospel-life-jesus/id967907349?mt=8):

[image: Select Bible book]

Comment: yeah i can but i need to display table view by selecting one below other not as above.Ex: in table view if i select first cell i need a list and if i select second view i need another list